# Check external IP from a Linux headless server

Tags: linux, networking, ip

I have access to a headless Debian server which I would like to learn the external IP address. How can I do that? The server is connected to the Internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will do the trick.

```
curl checkip.dyndns.org
```

Comment: lol I googled `checkip.dyndns.org` and there's a ton of *malware* warnings. Not saying it is for sure... but...

Comment: @KolobCanyon Then you should be Googling again, this time just the site name: you will see many sites stating something like *Once again,  chekcip.dns.org is not malicious*. Just try it for yourself. Besides, if you try the above command, you will see that the reply is simply: *<html><head><title>Current IP Check</title></head><body>Current IP Address: 11.22.33.44</body></html>*. It's hard to imagine where to hide malware in this. Mostly, this is slander from less reputable sites like *icanhazip*, trying to intercept a fraction of the traffic, that's all.

Comment: Fair enough. I ended up using `ifconfig.me` but yeah... it probably isnt malware. I'm just uncomfortable with `curl` or `wget` to a website I'm not sure I can trust. Seems like it would be easy to inject malicious code into the terminal

Answer (score 7):

This will do just fine and no need for `grep` :

```
curl icanhazip.com
```

You can use curl's `-4` and `-6` command line switches to explicitly request for a v4 or v6 IP address, the default being IPv6 if your network supports it.

Comment: Why should we trust a site like icanhazip?

Comment: Interesting point - why should we trust (or not trust) any site?

Comment: interesting point: fudge, fudge, and more fudge.

Answer (score 3):

You can use http://ipecho.net/plain with `lynx`, `wget`, or `curl`. I'm sure there are many, many others you could use it with too...

**lynx**

```
lynx --dump ipecho.net/plain
```

- **--dump** tells `lynx` to download the page and display it on stdout.

**curl**

```
curl ipecho.net/plain
```

**wget**

```
wget -q -O - ipecho.net/plain
```

- **-q** means *quiet* (i.e. do not display download progress).
- **-O** tells `wget` where to write the output to. The dash after it means stdout.

You can also use http://www.whatismyipaddress.com easily enough with `lynx`.

```
lynx --dump whatismyipaddress.com | grep "Your IP"
```

...and if you're really desperate, you're sure to be able to do it this rediculously complex way!

```
exec 3<>/dev/tcp/ipecho.net/80
echo -en "GET /plain HTTP/1.1\nHOST: ipecho.net\n\n" >&3
cat <&3
```

Output looks something like this...

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 28 Sep 2013 14:59:07 GMT
Server: Apache
Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html

d
76.177.248.16
0
```